# Validate extension in Paperclip - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I've found that Paperclip can validate file content type, i.e. image/jpeg, but I want to specifically validate the extension. This is because I'm working with an obscure extension that won't get a consistent content type.  Anyone know if this is doable, or a good way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Guess, there is no need to validate it with paperclip's method. You can rather use something like:

```
has_attached_file :attachment
validates_format_of :attachment_file_name, :with => %r{\.(docx|doc|pdf)$}i
```

**Edit:**

Alternatively, to validate it with paperclip:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :attachment, :content_type => 'text/plain'
```

^ it will generate content-type mismatch errors automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Simple follow-up: how can you customize the error message?  This doesn't seem to work:  validates_format_of :attachment_file_name, :with => %r{\.(txt)$}i, :message => "Can only upload .txt files."

Comment: That's weird! but anyway check the edit for alternate solution.

Comment: The second alternative here will probably also accept files with other file endings that have MIME type "text/plain". A number of such file endings can be found e.g. at [http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full).

Comment: That can be spoofed. Make sure to validate it a legitimate way besides matching the file name as well.