# How to set content_type for Fog storage in Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I am using paperclip for uploading files to S3 through Fog. However, I am having problem of setting the correct `content_type` for the text file. I have searched all places on the Internet but I have not found the solution for this issue. Do you have any idea how I can override content_type of fog storage?

Thanks

Comment: what about `'text/plain'` ?

Comment: Looks a lot like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554951/validate-extension-in-paperclip-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @JohnC By default, it is "text/plain". I want to make it "text/plain; charset=utf-8". The question in your link is different because I don't want to validate the content type but instead, I want to change the content type while saving

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue myself by overriding the UploadedFileAdapter in paperclip. I updated the function inside this class to something like this

```
def determine_content_type
  content_type = @target.content_type.to_s.strip
  if content_type_detector
    content_type = content_type_detector.new(@target.path).detect
  end

  #NOTE: override paperclip, need to set the utf-8 for text file
  content_type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8" if content_type == "text/plain"

  content_type
end
```